# Jquery Ajax pass JSON array format using the form data

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have an API integartion where the SMS service wants us to send data in this format with content-type as json.

```
{
  "from": "91887654681",
  "to": ["918757077777"],
  "body": "Hi this is my message using Mblox SMS REST API" 
}
```

I have a form with input texts namely from, to and body.

This is how my form submits.

```
$("#sendSMSForm").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // Serialize the form data.
    var form = $('#sendSMSForm');
    var formData = $(form).serialize();
    //alert(formData);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData
    }).done(function(response) {
        // Do some UI action stuff
        alert(response);
    });
});
```

I am not sure ...what should be used to pass a similar format.... of which the "to" is an array.

Comment: If you do this integration in client side jquery, someone is going to run up your SMS bill.  Handle this server side in PHP.  Why is this tagged with PHP anyway?

Answer (score 3):

Simply make your input fields `to` array

```
<input type="number" name="to[]" value="918757077777"/>
<input type="number" name="to[]" value="918757077778"/>
<input type="number" name="to[]" value="918757077779"/>
```

Comment: Yeah. That's right. You can consider this answer for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use jQuery Form plugin?
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started

You can use $.ajaxSubmit instead.

Answer (score 0):

@WEBjuju's comment was very helpful.... Why to do such Integrations in client side... its really a novice and bad practice. Finally I am managing this on the Server side...creating such json using PHP. Below is the sample that could help someone. This is a PHP function to make a HTTP REST call using cURL.

```
function callAPI($to, $body)
{
try{
 // I am creating an array of Whatever structure I need to pass to API
 $post_data = array('from' => ''.$this->from.'',
'to' => array(''.$to.''),
'body' => ''.$body.'');

//Set the Authorization header here... most APIs ask for this
$curl = curl_init();
$headers = array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

//If you have basic authorization, next 3 lines are required
$username ="venturecar15";
$password = "voaKmtWv";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD,  $username . ":" . $password); 

//Not receommended but worked for me
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->ApiURL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
//This is how we can convert an array to json       
$test = json_encode($post_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $test);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
} catch(Exception $e) {
   return "Exception: ".$e->getCode()." ".$e->getMessage();
}

if($result === FALSE) {
    $error = curl_error($curl)." ".curl_errno($curl);
    return "Error executing curl : ".$error;
}
 curl_close($curl);
return "SMS sent successfully to ".$to.".";
}
```